# How do I place decimals in a Meter to Milimeter converte in python?

Tags: python

I've trying to do an simple exercise where I need to Create an converter of meters to milimeters. The problem is, I am failing to make the code work with f-strings, so only numbers without decimals show up. How do I do that?

The current code:

```
print("meter to milimiter converter")
m = int(input(f"insert a number: "))
mm = m*1000
print(f"{mm:10.3f}")
```

Edit: my desired outcome is that I want it to work with decimals too

Comment: if you want no decimal places use `{mm:10.0f}`

Comment: If you want decimals for the input, you should use
`float(input("Insert a number: "))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Could you [edit] the question and add your desired output vs what you're getting currently? See [ask] for more advice.

Comment: Are you trying to convert numbers with `,`, for example `10,200.00`?

Comment: I am trying to convert numbers like 100.1334 , but it seems 10200.00 also doesnt work @AndrejKesely

Comment: @NewbieRose Your program will work, just change `int()` to `float()`, like this `m = float(input(f"insert a number: "))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely  It seems your solution solved the 10200 problem but it did not solve the other one. Numbers with 2+ numerals on the right side of the "point" do not work

Comment: @NewbieRose When I put `100.1334` as input the output is `100133.400` - is this correct?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes it does work! however when I put 101.1334 it just shows the same number

Comment: @NewbieRose When I input `101.1334` i see the result `101133.400`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Forget it, I am a idiot, I forgot to rerun the program, it works now, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert from string to float first

```
print("meter to milimiter converter")
m = float(input("insert a number: "))
mm = m * 1000
print(f"{mm:10.3f}")
```

Comment: `int(float())`? This doesn’t actually solve OP’s problem then, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to make this the second line:

m = float(input(f"insert a number: "))

Thanks to everyone who answered